All the lambdas (independent of each other) timing out before hitting the actual code/logic
I have 10 lambdas running and all of them are timing out even before executing the first log in the handler. So the timeout is not caused by anything in the code logic.
START RequestId: xyzzzzzz Version: $LATEST
xyzzzzzz Task timed out after 30.04 seconds
END RequestId: xyzzzzzzz

These are the only logs I get. I have given logs inside the actual code logic and inside the handler, but none of them got logged. And this is happening to all the lambdas and most of them are not dependent on each other at all and are under different API gateways as well.
These functions were working fine before and suddenly started to give a timeout even though there hasn't been any code or config changes done.
I had this issue before, where I had to delete the CloudFormation stack for all the lambdas and redeploy them to get it to work.
Any help is highly appreciated!
Thank you
I tried adding logs in the handler, redeploying the lambdas and API gateways and none of them seems to work.

Are your lambdas inside a VPC? Are you trying to connect to a client like RDS before executing your code in the lambda? Can you share more details about the code in lambda?

What's the lambda timeout time you have set?, looks like it's around 30 sec?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
